# Android app with hyphen unfindable in PlayStore without double quotes

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

We've just released an app to the PlayStore, and this app name contains a hyphen, which makes it unfindable in the PlayStore unless I enclose the name with double-quotes.

As far as the package name goes, the hyphen is replaced with an underscore there to follow the docs' conventions, so no problems there...

Can I fix the findability while keeping the hyphen, or alternatively can I remove the hyphen and republish without causing trouble for users who've already downloaded the app with its current name.

Answer (score 0):

First off, some general information about this can be found here

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9042516?hl=en

The title that is displayed in the playstore is just something you can change at any time through the developer console.

The actual title of the application can be changed in the `AndroidManifest`

```
<application
...
android:label="@string/app_name"
.../>
```

As long as you don't change the package name there should be no problem for current users.

Also, in my experience it takes quite some while before playstore search indexing is able to easily find your app with generic terms and strings. Brand new apps just have trouble showing up in general.

There is a reason why you can find `WhatsApp` with a completely misspelled word like: `what-app`. Basically the bigger you are, the more easily people can find you.